# JPA Hibernate Spring - no transaction opened

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, spring-transactions

I'm trying to use Hibernate with JPA in Spring transactions. All should work, but I think I missed something in configuration.

My persistence.xml file:

```
    <persistence-unit name="pzk" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
            value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My db-context.xml file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>     
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Of course I have `<tx:annotation-driven>, <context:annotation-config>,<context:component-scan basepackage="bla.bla.bla">` and my services are marked as `@Transactional`(tried to mark methods, classes and both)

The problem is, when I try to use collection of a model class in service, I get `LazyInitializationException`. Debug showed that no transaction is in progress. Could you please help with this?

P.S. Eager fetching works but this is not an option

Comment: I would also recommend entityManagerFactory's `<property name="packagesToScan" value="your.model.package"/>`, to get rid of persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing out to your transactionManager which entityManagerFactory it should work with.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```